# Java Game Keeps Freezing When I Start A Thread?

Tags: java, freeze, if-statement

I'm making a above mode 2D Zombie Shooter, and I'm having some problems with a thread. here's the deal. I had the character shoot a bullet every time i pressed space. the problem was that if you held space, it would shoot one, then pause, and then shoot a lot of bullets. there were a bunch of ways to fix this, but i want this way because it leaves room for future changes to shoot speed. here is the code for the thread that is causing the problems:

```
package threads;

import Game.GameCore;

public class Shoot extends GameCore implements Runnable {

/**
 * WHEN I START THIS THREAD, THE ENTIRE GAME FREEZES, AND I DO NOT KNOW
 * WHY... NEED TO FIX. IT DOES NOT FIX THE PROBLEM TO TAKE OUT THE "SHOOT"
 * OR THE "SLEEP"...
 */

public void run() {
    while (shooting && gameRunning) { // shooting is made true when space is
                                        // pressed, and set false when space
                                        // is released. gameRunning is true
                                        // if the game is running, which it
                                        // is. removing either of these
                                        // doesnt work either.
        player.shoot(); // player comes from the GameCore class, and
                        // represents the player entity. if i remove this,
                        // nothing changes.

        try {
            Thread.sleep(bulletShootSpeedMillis); // bulletShootSpeedMillis
                                                    // is equal to 1000, but
                                                    // makes no difference
                                                    // to change
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}

}
```

so here is the dang problem. the comments kinda point them out, but ill list them. if i remove the obvious things, such as `player.shoot();` or `Thread.sleep(bulletShootSpeedMillis);` or even one of the things in the while loop, nothing changes. the issue is that when i initiallize the thread, with

```
else if (key == Integer.parseInt(commands[6])) {
        shooting = true;
        new Thread(new Shoot()).run();
    }
```

the entire game just freezes. nothing happens at all. the moment i start the thread with space, my game freezes, and i cannot figure out why!!! the previous version with:

```
else if (key == Integer.parseInt(commands[6])) {
                    player.shoot();
            }
```

it works just fine. Please help! Thanks in advance! :)

**EDIT:** thanks for the quick answer. needless to say, major learning experience with simple mistakes XD

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Ayyyy!

```
new Thread(new Shoot()).run(); // ***** !!!!
```

You don't start a Thread by calling its `run()` method, since all that does is call the code in the *same* thread as the calling code. You start a *new* Thread by calling its `start()` method.

Comment: hmmm. well, that would be an issue... so then what does `run()` do?

Comment: @wbAnon: all `run()` does is call the `run()` method on the same thread as the calling code, not in a background thread. This is Thread 101 type stuff.

Comment: @wbAnon `run` is executed by the thread once it's started via `start`.  The intention is for you to override this method to provide functionality to the thread.

Comment: @MadProgrammer: he *does* override the method, so that's not the problem. The problem is that he's calling it directly rather than letting Thread's internal mechanisms call it by calling `start()`.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels Yep, I got that part, and yep, you are right he should be calling `start`, what I was trying to say (very badly apparently) is the `Thread` will execute `run` once it's running in the background - that's what I meant by "intention" - sorry for the confusion